# How to query Dynamic properties in NHibernate?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, dynamic, queryover

I have this problem.
I have a class like this:

```
public class WfStep
{
    private readonly IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();

    public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual dynamic Properties { get { return new HashtableDynamicObject(properties); } }
```

and its mapping file like this:

```
<class name="ConsoleApplication4.WfStep" table="WFSteps">

<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid"/>
</id>
<property name="Name" />

<map name="Properties" table="WFSteps_Properties" access="field.lowercase">
  <key column="StepId" />
  <index column="PropertyName" type="System.String"/>
  <composite-element class="ConsoleApplication4.ValueItem, ConsoleApplication4">
    <property name="Value" type="System.String"/>
    <property name="ValueType" type="System.String"/>
  </composite-element>
</map>
```

This example is ported from: 
[Ayende Support dynamic fields with NHibernate and .NET 4.0](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/03/08/support-dynamic-fields-with-nhibernate-and-.net-4.0.aspx)

Then I save an object to the db like this:
ie.

```
var step = new WfStep { Name = "John" };
var property = new ValueItem() { Value = DateTime.Now, ValueType = "System.DateTime" };
step.Properties["DateProperty"] = property ;

Session.Save(step);
```

Now I want to return all the WFSteps that have DateProperty set to year 2010 ie.:

```
var Session.Query<WfStep>().Where(x=>x.Properties.DateProperty.Year == 2010);
```

It throws an error:

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

How can I query this type of class that has Dynamic properties.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index collections mapped as a map or as list. Try the following hql

```
from WfStep s
where s.Properties["DateProperty"] = "2010"
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want to use hql, for this. Only QueryOver or Linq.

Comment: Have you tried doing `.Where(x => x.Properties["DateProperty"] = "2010")`?